# Can Can with Role Model restriction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I'm Trying to achieve that the user can see only HIS applications, and not the "Application Index" containing all the applications from all Users.

My Header:

```
 <%= link_to "My Application ", current_user.application %>
```

My Abilities:

```
 if user.has_role? :speaker
  can :read, Application do |application| # heres the problem
    application.try(:user) == user
  end
  can :create, Application
  can :update, Application do |application|
    application.try(:user) == user
  end
end
```

Currently the User can access the Application/Index page. But the restriction should give him only access to:

```
http://localhost:3000/applications/8 # 8 being his application
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: My gut tells me there is a different way to do this (although I'm not sure what)... however, maybe you could try changing this line: `application.try(:user) == user` to `application.try(:user_id) == user`

Comment: Hey Rich, good thought but this raises a General Exception from can can.. The user can't view his own application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be not the cleanest way, but this works:

in `index` action:

```
if current_user.has_role? :admin
  @applications = Application.all
else
  @applications = current_user.application
end
```

in `index.html.erb`

```
<% if current_user.has_role? :admin %>
  <%= render @applications %>
<% else %>
  <% @applications.title %> etc..
<% end %>
```

**Note**: `current_user.application` is because `user` model `has_one :application`